# Cloning a div and making it appear on the screen isn't working

Tags: jquery

Below is my code (don't worry about 'off', it's the offset based on the where the user clicks). In the second line I am trying to clone an existing div and then show the cloned copy? But it doesn't work. However if I remove clone() then the code does work, but of course it simply shows the existing div which isn't what I need.

```
var off = $(this).offset();
var div = $('#testtt').clone();
div.css({ position: "absolute", top: off.top, left: off.left });
div.show();
```

Any tips?

Comment: Why you don't use $(this).clone(); ?

Comment: this isn't the element I want to clone but the element I am clicking on.

Comment: Probably because you aren't attaching the cloned element to the DOM anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are cloning the div **but not inserting** it anywhere in your DOM..

So it is non existent until you do that

```
var off = $(this).offset();
var div = $('#testtt').clone();
div.css({ position: "absolute", top: off.top, left: off.left });

$('body').append(div);   <-- Appending to body here.. You can append anywhere you want
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to append div to your page.  Currently, you have just created a reference to the clone without displaying it.

$("body").append(div);

Answer (score 1):

You have to attach the cloned div somewhere inside your html.
For example:

```
var off = $(this).offset();
var div = $('#testtt').clone();
div.css({ position: "absolute", top: off.top, left: off.left });

// append to parent of "this"
var parent = $(this).parent();
div.appendTo(parent);

// should be unnecessary, except if the style is display:none
//div.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append it to another element by using `append()` or `appendTo()`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably an issue with duplicate id's

From the [API page](http://api.jquery.com/clone/):

> Note: Using .clone() has the side-effect of producing elements with
>   duplicate id attributes, which are supposed to be unique. Where
>   possible, it is recommended to avoid cloning elements with this
>   attribute or using class attributes as identifiers instead.

After cloning, try changing the id of the cloned element:

```
div.attr('id').val('#testtt')
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment from @andrewWhitaker, you need to add the new element to the DOM.  e.g.

```
div.attr('id').val( div.attr('id')+"_cloned" );
$("#my_container_element_id").append(div);
```

You can also remove the

```
div.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

in Jquery

```
$('.addRow').click(function(){
var off = $(this).offset();
var div = $('#testtt').clone();
div.css({ position: "absolute", top: off.top, left: off.left });
div.show();
div.appendTo($("#testtt");
```

})